# Тип Memo в Firebird

Tags: firebird, sql

Какой тип в Firebird соответсвтует memo и как его объявлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VarChar**
 и указывайте длину

Answer (score 1):

Если длина неизвестна или потенциально не ограничена, то `blob sub_type text`.

Подробно о типе данных BLOB можно почитать в официальной документации [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference (Russian)](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/Firebird_Language_Reference_RUS.pdf), страницы 34-35